# Get an access to JFrame components

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jfreechart

How to get an access to the `XYSeries` and `XYPlot` placed on `JFrame`? Of course, I can use the variable names `series` and `plot`, but my question refers to the functional way to access these components, i.e. `f.getContentPane()`... This is useful when the function returns `JFrame`.

```
JFrame f = new JFrame(title);
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 5));
XYSeries series = new XYSeries("");
XYDataset data = createDataset(series,0,indf,oldpop);
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createScatterPlot(title, xtitle, ytitle, data, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer =
                (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setBaseShapesVisible(true);          plot.getDomainAxis().setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
f.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
chartPanel.setMouseWheelEnabled(true);
chartPanel.setHorizontalAxisTrace(true);
chartPanel.setVerticalAxisTrace(true);
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
f.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: this is about to define `Objectss as `local variables`, instead of iterating inside arrays of `for (Component comp : container.getComponents()) {` and to testing Object with `instanceof whatever`

Comment: @mKorbel: I tested this code: for (Component comp : f1.getContentPane().getComponents()) {
         if (comp instanceof XYSeries)
         {
        //...  
         }
        }. It cannot be compiled because of Component (incompatibe...)

Comment: whats returns debugger, whats type of Object, before instanceof is executed (or disabled), not XxxChart or XxxGraph user, but could be based on AWT Containers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ChartPanel` is `JComponent` which renders `JFreeChart`; both `XYSeries` and `XYPlot` are components, these objects used by `JFreeChart`. Since they're not components, you can't access them by traversing component hierarchy, you have to get them from `ChartPanel` and `JFreeChart`.

Find `ChartPanel` in the component hierarchy, use `getChart()` to get `JFreeChart` object, and then get the objects you want from it, just like you do in the code above:

```
XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
```